# Catch a Json string (made using dot net , newtonsoft) in android using Volley.

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

I need to catch a json string (in my case: ["Java","C","C++"]) in android app using Volley and put it inside a String array courseList.
A few closing brackets may be missing, sorry for that, there is more code in my file, but i could not copy it whole.Please provide code if u can, it will b really helpful. Thanks)
 Here is my attempted code:

```
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ListView simpleList;

        final String[] courseList = new String[3];// = {"HR","C Programming", "C++","C#", "Java", "Javascript", "Angular JS", "Data Structure", "Ajax", "Asp.Net", "jQuery", "json", "SQL"};
        int flags[] = {R.drawable.hr,R.drawable.cprogramming, R.drawable.cplus, R.drawable.csharp, R.drawable.java, R.drawable.javascript, R.drawable.angularjs, R.drawable.datastructures, R.drawable.ajax, R.drawable.aspnet, R.drawable.jquery, R.drawable.json, R.drawable.sql};

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // for volley
        String jsonURL = "http://192.168.0.131:10462/WebService1.asmx";
        final String data = "";
        RequestQueue requestQueue;

        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        JSONObject jsonRequest = new JSONObject();
        try {
            jsonRequest.put("GetTopic",Request.Method.GET );
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(jsonURL,jsonRequest,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                // Takes the response from the JSON request
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject("GetTopic");
                        // Retrieves the string labeled "colorName" and "description" from
                        //the response JSON Object
                        //and converts them into javascript objects
                        String color = obj.getString("GetTopic");
                       // Adds strings from object to the "data" string
                        String data = "Topic Name: " + color ;
                                // Adds the data string to the TextView "results"
                       // results.setText(data);
                        courseList[0] = data;
                        courseList[1] = data;
                        courseList[2] = data;

                       // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),data,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    // Try and catch are included to handle any errors due to JSON
                    catch (JSONException e) {
                        // If an error occurs, this prints the error to the log
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },  new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                // Handles errors that occur due to Volley
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e("Volley", "Error");
                }
            });

        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);

        CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(), courseList, flags);
}
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: @ruben, i want courseList[0] = "Java" ,courseList[1]= "C" , courseList[2]="C++". No errors but what is desire is not happening, can u tell where i am wrong. and the right way to do it.

Comment: LogCat shows this.
03-28 10:10:37.697 7816-7816/com.example.sunplus_prathap.suniq E/Volley: Error
03-28 10:10:37.697 7816-7816/com.example.sunplus_prathap.suniq D/Volley: [1] Request.finish: 7593 ms: [ ] http://192.168.0.131:10462/WebService1.asmx 0x85adf6b2 NORMAL 1

Comment: change your `log` statetment to `Log.e("Volley", "Error :"+error);` and check the logcat to see your error

Comment: please share your json response...

Comment: [
    {
        "topicId": 2,
        "topicName": "Java"
    },
    {
        "topicId": 3,
        "topicName": "C"
    },
    {
        "topicId": 4,
        "topicName": "C++"
    },
    {
        "topicId": 5,
        "topicName": "JavaScript"
    },
   ]